# Missing method in EnableCorsAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I want to enable CORS from my controller into asp.net core 2 application, so into controller I add attribute like:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "accept,content-type,origin,x-my-header", methods: "*")]
```

But I get error on origins:

> The best overload for 'EnableCorsAttribute' does not have a parameter
>   named 'origins'

So I access to EnableCorsAttribute from meta data and I found this methods:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
{

    public class EnableCorsAttribute : Attribute, IEnableCorsAttribute
    {
        public EnableCorsAttribute(string policyName);

        public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But is supposly it be a method like this:

```
public EnableCorsAttribute(string origins, string headers, string methods);
```

Why I don't have it? I need to install something? I'm new in Asp.Net Core and I don't understand why that method isn't in my api. Regards

Comment: Can I ask where you got the impression that it "should" have three parameters? Is that from some documentation somewhere? If so, could you link to it?

Comment: @JonSkeet https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/configure-cors-using-appsettings-or-custom-configuration-sections-in-aspnet-web-api#add-cors-support-to-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such attribute like `EnableCorsAttribute(string origins, string headers, string methods)` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` package.

In Your scenario and based on [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1):
If provided cors configuration is for whole app then in Your `ConfigureServices` method add cors services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

and then global cors middleware in `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("https://my.web.com", "http://localhost:5001")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type", "Origin", "X-My-Header"));

    //code omitted
}
```

Replace `("https://my.web.com", "http://localhost:5001")` with your origin(s).
In case You would like to have more than one cors configuration then in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("https://my.web.com", "http://localhost:5001")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .WithHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type", "Origin", "X-My-Header"));
    });
}
```

in `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");

    //code omitted
}
```

and finally in controller:

```
[EnableCors("MyCorsPolicy")]
public class MyController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Comment: I try as you say and I getting `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Comment: If you are sending request with credentials flag then you need to set specific origin domains, eg. `WithOrigins("http://localhost:1233")` and `.AllowCredentials()`. I'll update my answer to reflect that.